# Post-Increment Operator: Unexpected Behavior

Tags: c, gcc, post-increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int x = 10, y = 0;
  x = x++;
  printf("x: %d\n", x);
  y = x++;
  printf("y: %d\n", y);
}
```

Given the nature of post-increment, I would expect the following output:

```
x: 10
y: 10
```

My reasoning is that in line 5, `x` should be assigned to its initial value after the increment takes place.

Instead, however, I get this:

```
x: 11
y: 11
```

Digging into the assembly, this looks like a deliberate choice to me:

```
LCFI2:
        movl    $10, -4(%rbp)   // this is x
        movl    $0, -8(%rbp)    // this is y
        incl    -4(%rbp)        // x is simply incremented
        movl    -4(%rbp), %esi
        leaq    LC0(%rip), %rdi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    _printf
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  // now x is saved in a register,
        movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)  // copied to y,
        incl    -4(%rbp)        // and finally incremented
        movl    -8(%rbp), %esi
        leaq    LC1(%rip), %rdi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    _printf
```

What's going on here?  Is GCC trying to save me from myself?  I don't have a language reference handy but I would have thought that this breaks the intended semantics.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Comment: In the bad old days, `a = 1 + a` in certain languages was a mine that all the new bugs would tread on.

Comment: @caf - you are right, this is a duplicate (although that question unfortunately provides no helpful way to search for it).

Comment: When you say "Instead, however, I get this: x = 11, y =11" , what compiler are you using. I checked on codeblocks and onlinegdb, they both gave me x=10 , y = 10 as expected.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The behaviour is undefined as there is no intervening sequence point in `x = x++`, see e.g. the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html).

Comment: Thanks!  I was not previously aware of sequence points.

Answer (score 4):

It is left undefined by the C language as to when exactly a post/pre-in/decrement occurs. Thus, statements such as `x = x++` are not well formed - avoid them.

Comment: More precisely you aren't allowed to modify a variable more than once in an expression. 6.5/2: *"Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression."*

Comment: @sth: More precisely, "more than one between sequence points". It's possible for an expression to contain a sequence point, in which case modifying a variable more than once is fine. For example, `&&`, `||` and the comma operator can all form sequence points within a single expression.

Comment: @sth: Even _more precisely_, that's not a limitation on the coder, it's a limitation on the variable itself. Your statement that you "aren't allowed to ..." is not quite correct. You _are_ allowed to, it's just a very silly thing to do :-)

Comment: Yeah, I was aware that the use of the word "precisely" there would cause some follow-up comments. But it was late at night and I was too lazy to explain what a sequence point is... :)

Answer (score 2):

Standards aside (since this is undefined with respect to the standard), the way it ran is the way I would have expected it.

My rule of thumb is that for a line with `x++`, you substitute `x++` with `x` and put `x += 1` on the following line (or preceding line for pre-increment).

Following that rule of thumb, your code would be written as

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int x = 10, y = 0;
  x = x; // x: 10
  x += 1; // x: 11
  printf("x: %d\n", x);
  y = x; // y: 11
  x += 1; // x: 12
  printf("y: %d\n", y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have:

```
a = b++;
```

what is happening is that b is saved to a and after the assigment is done b is incremented by one. So if you do:

```
x = x ++;
```

and previously x was 10 what will happen is 10 will be saved to x and after(before your printf is done) x is incremented by one to 11. That's why 11 is printed.